Getting "System.ObjectDisposedException : Cannot access a closed file." while Windows native API migration
I'm working on an ASP.NET framework project where I need to remove the native Windows API call to reopen a file with a specific file access and file share.
Current implementation:
var handle = NativeMethods.ReOpenFile(existingHandle, desiredAccess, share, options);

Here is the implementation for NativeMethods.ReOpenFile():
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern SafeFileHandle ReOpenFile(SafeFileHandle hOriginalFile, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FILE_ACCESS dwAccess, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileShare dwShareMode, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileOptions dwFlags);

I need to remove the native Windows API (kernel32.dll) call.
So I removed the native API and replaced NativeMethods.ReopenFile() with the following:
existingHandle.Dispose();
var file = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, access, share);
var handle = file.SafeFileHandle;

But this throws the following exception:

System.ObjectDisposedException : Cannot access a closed file.

So how can I remove the windows native API call and preserve the existing functionality?
